# Stopping MySql server on Linux (to try and reset root password)

Tags: mysql, linux

I was trying to stop mysql on Ubuntu to follow the steps explained here on how to reset the password:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/resetting-permissions.html
the problem is whenever I kill mysqld process, it gets spawned again.

Any idea how to force stopping it or figuring out what's starting it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do such command for older ubuntu, as said in http://www.codeunit.co.za/2010/07/07/how-to-start-or-stop-mysql-server-on-ubuntu-via-the-command-line/

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
```

And for newest ubuntu, the [`upstart` program](http://upstart.ubuntu.com) manages mysqld running all time... [use command as said here](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#stop)

```
sudo initctl stop mysql
```

or

```
sudo stop mysql
```

Answer (score 2):

The mysql process is probably started by some daemon control software which also automatically respawns it. Try using `ps` to determine its parent process, which will give you a hint how to stop it:

```
ps -fC mysqld
```

and look into the PPID column. If it's a 1, the process is owned directly by init and a simple kill should suffice to stop it. If not, use something like

```
ps -fp 1234
```

to display the process that sired the mysql process, it will probably be responsible for its respawn.

Answer (score 1):

## To install MySql database:

sudo apt-get install mysql-server

## To start MySql server:

/etc/init.d/mysql start

## To stop MySql server:

/etc/init.d/mysql stop

## To restart MySql server:

/etc/init.d/mysql restart

## To check the status of  MySql server:

/etc/init.d/mysql status

Comment: will it work on ubuntu 11.04 or 11.10 or 12.04 or .. ?

Answer (score 1):

The later versions of Ubuntu uses [Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) for its init system. Its been a while, but I think the syntax to stop a service would be something like:

```
stop servicename
```